# Is "I can't get to know[..]" incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

A past question I wrote was corrected, from:

> But I **can't get to know** how to precisely perform them

to:

> But I **don't know** how to consistently perform them

( https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/16202/revisions )

To me it felt like my version implied that I tried many times but ultimately failed. The second version doesn't have this implication.

So, was my first formulation really incorrect? If so, how can I formulate this in order to emphasize the fact I tried many times and still failed to understand ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your original version is that the phrase *to get to know* is an idiom that refers to coming to know someone personally. It would be normal English to say:

> I got to know John after hanging out with him at a party.
>
> I can't really get to know Mary because she lives so far away.

It sounds very odd to use the phrase *to get to know* to describe coming to know intellectual knowledge or learning how to perform a particular technique. To express failure to acquire impersonal knowledge after multiple tries, you could say:

> I still can't *figure out*...
>
> I can't *wrap my head around*...
>
> I still *don't get it*.

Or any number of other formulations.

Comment: +1, nice write up; following it further, I think it is ok to push the idiom on any subject, *if* you personify it: e.g. ”I am getting to know all the moods of the storage system.”, ”I can't really get to know how it would behave in VM because I don't have permissions to create one to play with it.”

Comment: +1 I'd nearly finished typing my answer making the same points less eloquently. For the first time ever, I clicked on "Load new Answer" to see yours before posting mine. So the upvote is partly for a good answer, partly for sparing me the humiliation of offering up a poor imitation of it! :)

Comment: @Unreason: I wouldn't try to extend the "idiom" as you suggest. The first one might be okay (except I have no idea what the "moods" of a storage system could mean). But the second one is just pointless verbosity that would be better as just *know, learn, see,* or *establish*.

Comment: @Aleanno, just tried to pint out that idiom can be used also in another scenario. Just thought of another example: *I am getting to know what it means to address someone properly.* JSBᾶngs' definition (coming to know someone personally) seems to apply only when there is a simple, direct object.

Comment: I didn't know "get to know" refers to knowing someone, thanks for the clarification. I think "I still can't figure out" is what I was looking for.